# How can I get my python window to run in the foreground constantly?

Tags: python, webview, win32gui

I have created a window that links to a website and would like it to stay on top of all other programs at all times, but I can't find a way to succeed in that regard.

```
import win32gui
import webview

webview.create_window('Fame', url='https://livecounts.io/youtube-live-subscriber-counter/UC18JhJPfJpw3py3CJs5Z1dQ', js_api=None, width=600, height=400,
                      x=1350, y= -60, resizable=False, fullscreen=False, \
                      min_size=(200, 100), hidden=False, frameless=True, \
                      minimized=False, confirm_close=False, background_color='#FFF', \
                      text_select=False,)
webview.start()
Helpme = 1
while Helpme <= 2 :
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow('Fame')
```

The idea that I had the most hope for thus far was the while loop, but it is unfortunately not working as intended.